How to get the average of another min/max aggregate in Clickhouse?
I have a flow of events
{
  "cid": <UUID>
  "sid": <UUID>
  "timestamp": DateTime
}

I need to group them by sid and get the diff between the max and min timestamp (= duration).
For this I figured out I could one one of:

deltaSumTimestamp.
min and max and do a max - min

Then I need to group by cid and get the average duration.

Given a first table by_sid:
CREATE TABLE by_sid
(
    cid UUID,
    sid UUID,
    start_time SimpleAggregateFunction(min, DateTime),
    latest_activiy_time SimpleAggregateFunction(max, DateTime),
    duration AggregateFunction(deltaSumTimestamp, DateTime, DateTime)
)
engine = AggregatingMergeTree()
ORDER BY (cid, sid);

and its mat view
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW by_sid_mv TO by_sid
AS SELECT
    raw.cid, raw.sid
    min(raw.timestamp) AS start_time,
    max(raw.timestamp) AS latest_activiy_time,
    deltaSumTimestampState(raw.timestamp, raw.timestamp) AS duration
FROM raw
GROUP BY raw.cid, raw.sid;

This is going well so far. My pain point is now creating another table by_cid which is pushing the grouping and getting the average duration.
I've been trying the following:
CREATE TABLE by_cid
(
    cid UUID,
    average_time AggregateFunction(avg, Int32)
)
engine = AggregatingMergeTree()
ORDER BY (cid);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW by_cid_mv TO by_cid
AS SELECT
    cid,
    avgState(latest_activiy_time - start_time) AS average_time
FROM by_sid
GROUP BY cid;

But average_time keeps being equal to 0.
SELECT avgMerge(average_time) FROM by_cid

Query id: ea24d5d0-00a0-473e-ae63-b0c3b6dcc681

   ┌─avgMerge(average_time)─┐
1. │                      0 │
   └────────────────────────┘

1 row in set. Elapsed: 0.003 sec. 

And I guess it is due to the fact that, events being incoming with a few seconds interval, they do not come up in the same data block. Therefore, considering a single event at a time, the duration will be 0 as it only contains 1 timestamp. So averaging 0 with 0 will always result in 0.
We can observe this:
SELECT * FROM page_session

Query id: 0c16f311-1b79-4c8a-a620-83d1e2896b1a

   ┌─cid──────────────────────────────────┬─sid──────────────────────────────────┬─latest_activiy_time─┬──────────start_time─┐
1. │ 950b1225-f77e-4222-9ac5-0cdfed19a8ed │ e7b8ad13-5136-4dae-8faf-3d5f13ed4eb7 │ 2024-11-27 16:01:13 │ 2024-11-27 16:01:13 │
   └──────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
   ┌─cid──────────────────────────────────┬─sid──────────────────────────────────┬─latest_activiy_time─┬──────────start_time─┐
2. │ 950b1225-f77e-4222-9ac5-0cdfed19a8ed │ e7b8ad13-5136-4dae-8faf-3d5f13ed4eb7 │ 2024-11-27 16:01:06 │ 2024-11-27 16:01:06 │
   └──────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘

2 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.003 sec. 


select max(latest_activiy_time), min(start_time), deltaSumTimestampMerge(duration) from by_sid

Query id: 2833696a-44ce-43b5-a45d-f6d17bb2d6ba

   ┌─max(latest_activiy_time)─┬──────min(start_time)─┬─deltaSumTimestampMerge(duration)─┐
1. │      2024-11-27 16:01:13 │  2024-11-27 16:01:06 │                                7 │
   └──────────────────────────┴──────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────┘

1 row in set. Elapsed: 0.008 sec. 

I tried using the deltaSumTimestamp:
CREATE TABLE by_cid_2
(
    cid UUID,
    average_time AggregateFunction(avg, UInt32)
)
engine = AggregatingMergeTree()
ORDER BY (cid);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW by_cid_2_mv TO by_cid_2
AS SELECT
    cid,
    avgState(duration) AS average_time
FROM (
    SELECT
        cid,
        deltaSumTimestampMerge(duration) AS duration
    FROM by_sid
    GROUP BY cid, sid
)
GROUP BY cid;

Same issue.
I ran the OPTIMIZE queries to force the merge of my data blocks but it did not fix the result.
I would appreciate any clue or suggestion. Thanks.
